# getting word-level encodings from sub-word tokens encodings

Tags: nlp, tokenize, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm looking into using a pretrained BERT ('bert-base-uncased') model to extract contextualised word-level encodings from a bunch sentences.

Wordpiece tokenisation breaks down some of the words in my input into subword units. Possibly a trivial question, but I was wondering what would be the most sensible way to combine output encodings for subword tokens into word-level encodings.

Is averaging subword encodings a reasonable way to go? If not, is there any better alternative?

Comment: I guess this depends on the task you try to solve with those embeddings. What is your goal?

Comment: fairly general encoding purpose, we want to featurize the stimulus for a range of possible usage cases. Words occur in complex stimulus (narratives) for which we have metadata at word level (e.g. onsets of each word), which is why we need to preserve word-level encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, your problem seems similar to "how to get a good sentence representation", with the exception that these days you could also use a classification token of a sentence to get a sentence representation in most transformer-based models. Such token is not available for token-level representations, though.

In your case, I think there are a few options but from what I've seen, people most often use either an average or a max value. In other words: take the average of your subword units, or take the max values. Averaging is the most intuitive place to start, in my opinion.

Note that averages are only just that, an average over a sequence. This implies that it is not super accurate (one high and one low value will have the same mean as two medium values), but it's probably the most straightforward.